# Is there a way to reference the condition of a conditional statement or loop?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is it possible to directly reference the condition of, for instance, an if statement?

```
if (true) {
    // Reference to the condition of the if statement
}
```

What I want to get from the code above is `true` since that is the condition for the if statement.

Can this be done using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Eh? The question is...?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If the body of the statement is executed you already know that the condition resolved to `true`.

Comment: Nothing to do with jQuery. You can do `var x; if (x = expression) { /* use x */ }` but only if the value of the expression is truthy. Certainly not recommended.

Comment: @FelixKling Not what the condition resolved to, but what the condition itself is.

Comment: You cannot reference syntax at runtime if that's what you mean (unless you put it in a string and `eval` it). If you would tell us what you are trying to achieve we may be able to help. But as it is the answer is just "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you want to be secure and in keeping with good practice, there's not. You can determine whether the expression evaluated to `true` or `false`, but since that's all that happens inside an `if` statement, you can't access the original syntax of the statement.

If you *really* wanted to do it, the only possible way would be to firstly save the expression in a string, and then `eval` the string inside the `if` statement.

```js
const exp = "x == 3";
const x = 3;
if (eval(exp)) {
  console.log("True");
} else {
  console.log("False");
}
```